# change background image of navigation bar based on orientation

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to change the background image of navigation bar based on orientation? I tried using methods in the app delegate such as :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame

{

 UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

if(orientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)||orientation==(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown)){

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"borderP.png"];
    UIImage * imageBottom = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomP.png"];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:imageBottom forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:myImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:imageBottom forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    NSLog(@"******P******");
}

else if(orientation == (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft||orientation== UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)){


    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"borderL.png"];
    UIImage * imageBottom = [UIImage imageNamed:@"borderL.png"];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:imageBottom forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:myImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:imageBottom forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    NSLog(@"******L********");
}

}
```

but the back ground image does not change.

Any advice?

Comment: thank you for clearing that up, im trying to modify an existing one

Answer (score 0):

The appearance proxy only applies only to new instances. To modify an instance that already exists, you you need to call `setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:` on it directly.

Comment: tried this but it does not work as you suggested `UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;`
        `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"borderL.png"];
        [navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: Do you get the proper P and L log messages?  Are `navBar` and `image` non-nil?

Comment: Sending a message to `nil` is a no-op, so thats the reason it isn't doing anything.